# python: box plot(or violin plot) from multidimensional data

Tags: python

I'm new to python and have no backgrounds at all.
The thing is I'd like to create box or violin plot from multidimensional data set such as, 20 groups having 5 variables. 
Each group has 20~100 elements (raw data before averaging)
Which function can help me parsing this? 
In matlab I think cell array would be helpful but I guess there is more brilliant way to parse this data in python.
Please help..

Comment: I think it should be variable by variable graph. meaning, graphing 20 groups for variable 1, 20 groups for variable 2 ... so on..

Answer (score 0):

There is a very useful python package called [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) you can use to draw box plot or violin plot. Below is a example of box plot vs violin plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(9, 4))

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


# generate some random test data
all_data = [np.random.normal(0, std, 100) for std in range(6, 10)]

# plot violin plot
axes[0].violinplot(all_data,
                  showmeans=False,
                  showmedians=True)
axes[0].set_title('Violin plot')

# plot box plot
axes[1].boxplot(all_data)
axes[1].set_title('Box plot')

# adding horizontal grid lines
for ax in axes:
    ax.yaxis.grid(True)
    ax.set_xticks([y + 1 for y in range(len(all_data))])
    ax.set_xlabel('Four separate samples')
    ax.set_ylabel('Observed values')

# add x-tick labels
plt.setp(axes, xticks=[y + 1 for y in range(len(all_data))],
     xticklabels=['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

There are more examples in matplotlib's [gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#).I hope you can find a example which can satisfy you.

Comment: thanks you! but could you help me a bit more? 

df = pd.read_excel('AA screening male.xlsx', index_col=0)
df.groupby('#').groups.keys()
sns.boxplot(x='?????',y='Sleep Amount (min)', data=df)
in this context I'd like to put groups('#';ranging from 1to20) within x-axis. how can I put it in there.
thanks again!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to put 20 box plots in a figure from 1 to 20?

Comment: no, 20 x-ticks for one figure. but I have 5 different variables like : sleep amount, waking activity, etc ... , which will be pictured in independent figures. so total figure would be 5.

Comment: I found that 
df.boxplot(column='Sleep Amount (min)', by='#')
is working for my data but violinplot instead of boxplot does now work. do you have any idea of it? And how can I implant seaborn style in here? thanks!

Comment: I somehow figured it out! thanks for your kind help :D

Comment: Congratulations!